# How to sort an array of arrays by a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my array rows on the bases of **MYCOUNT** index which is calculated by my code. **MYCOUNT** is calculated number of matched words in **KEYWORDS**. I have google different functions but i never got required result. I am new in php i have no idea how to do it and i never found result on google which can help me.

```
$word = "red pent";
$flag = true;
$main_flag = true;
$list = array();
$result = $this->db->get('products')->result_array();
foreach ($result as $product):
    $main_flag = true;
    $keywords = explode(';', $product['product_keyword']);
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($keywords as $keys) {
        $search = explode(' ', $word);
        $local_f = false;
        foreach ($search as $w) {
            if (strtolower(trim($w)) === strtolower(trim($keys))) {
                $local_f = true;
                $count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($count > 0) {
        $product['mycount'] = $count;
        array_push($list, $product);
    }
    if ($main_flag) {
        //array_push($list,$product);
    }
endforeach;
```

**Array Data**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_sku] => AD021CAFOR
            [product_code] => X12343
            [product_name] => Ten aZ Cap
            [product_price] => 600
            [product_actual_price] => 2000
            [product_discount] => 70
            [product_gender] => MEN
            [product_group] => Accessories
            [product_category] => Cap
            [product_sub_category] => 
            [product_sport] => Training
            [product_weight] => 
            [outlet_id] => 1
            [product_desc] => Adidas Ten aZ Cap CLIMACOOL
            [product_short_desc] => Adidas Ten aZ Cap CLIMACOOL
            [product_added_on] => 2014-02-20
            [product_updated_on] => 
            [product_image] => image1.png
            [product_thumbnail] => image1.png;image2.png;image3.png;image4.png;image5.png;image6.png
            [product_list_image] => rightside-list1_03.png
            [product_keyword] => Red;shirt;adidas
            [mycount] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 6
            [product_sku] => AD021CAFRO
            [product_code] => X17618
            [product_name] => Ess 3S fit Cap
            [product_price] => 600
            [product_actual_price] => 2000
            [product_discount] => 70
            [product_gender] => MEN
            [product_group] => Accessories
            [product_category] => Cap
            [product_sub_category] => 
            [product_sport] => Training
            [product_weight] => 
            [outlet_id] => 1
            [product_desc] => The adidas Performance ESS 3S Cap has a curved peak and features neon adidas 3 stripes detailing on the front. The cap is made from a breathable, 100% cotton fabric and has an adjustable strap on the back.
            [product_short_desc] => Essentials 3 Stripes Cap
            [product_added_on] => 2014-02-20
            [product_updated_on] => 
            [product_image] => image1.png
            [product_thumbnail] => image1.png;image2.png;image3.png;image4.png;image5.png;image6.png
            [product_list_image] => rightside-list1_03.png
            [product_keyword] => red;pent;outfiters
            [mycount] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to sort based on user defined criteria you use [the sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) that allow "user defined" sorting, such as [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
function sortby_mycount_asc($a, $b) {
    return $a["mycount"] - $b["mycount"];
}
uasort($product, "sortby_mycount_asc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working in my case

```
function cmp($a, $b) {

        if ($a['mycount'] == $b['mycount']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    uasort($list,"cmp");
```